# Drupal 6 oracle database connection

Tags: database, oracle, drupal

I want to connect drupal 6.X verstion with oracle database. So, Is there any step by
step guide available So, I can connect drupal 6.x with oracle database.

Please let me know.

Thank you,
Mrugesh Panchal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal 6 does not support Oracle.

There is a [module](http://drupal.org/project/oracle), but most contributed modules are not going to work with Oracle.

Comment: Dear Berdir, I got succeed in connectiong with oracle database and displaying oracle records using oci8 module. It is really wonderfull module which connects to the oracle db. and fetch record according to node id.